# Second click on button to send form?

Tags: ajax, forms, button, submit

I'm working on a delete function in a web app where clicking on a button deletes a row in my db. This is pretty straight forward and it works, but I want the user to be able to confirm the delete first before the form is submitted.

Here's the markup for the form as it is now:

```
echo '<li class="fave-item">';
echo '<div class="tasted-this box-center">';
echo '<form class="delete-fave">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$faves_result['user_id'].'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="beer_id" value="'.$faves_result['beer_id'].'" />';
echo '<button class="icon delete" data-icon="x" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</li>';
```

And here's the ajax submit func.:

```
$('.delete-fave').on('submit', function(){
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "deletefave.php",  
    data: $(this).serialize(),  
    success: $.proxy(function(json) {  
      $(this).closest('li.fave-item').remove();
    },this)  
  });
  return false; 
});
```

This is what I want to happen before the submit:

```
$('button.delete').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass('delete-fave');
  $(this).addClass('ready');
  return false;    
});
```

When I tested this I removed the class from the form to achieve this order of events:

1. Click 'button.delete' adds class 'delete-fave' to form (making it active)
2. 'button.delete' gets a 'ready' class
3. Clicking again on button with the 'ready' class submits form.

I haven't been able to merge these functions so I hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$('.delete-fave').on('submit'...` function is defined BEFORE the class is added to the `button.delete` parent, so it's not going to work.

To get it to work just redefine the function again AFTER adding the class.

JSFiddle recreating your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rowlandrose/XAeCh/5/

JSFiddle solving your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rowlandrose/XAeCh/4/

Comment: Hi Rowland, thank you! Here's what made it work:
    `$('button.delete').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('delete-fave'); 
        $(this).addClass('ready');
        $('button.ready').click(function(){
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "deletefave.php",  
                data: $(this).serialize(),  
                success: $.proxy(function(json) {  
                    $(this).closest('li.fave-item').remove();
                },this)  
            });
            return false; 
        });
        return false;
    });`